# IndexError: only integers, slices

Tags: python

I'm starting with python and found github site https://github.com/yohanesnuwara/computational-geophysics/tree/e423deb73e8aa811222863ccf80057cca6224553/seismic with seismic tools. Unfortunatelly I have issue with some code in seis_attribute_notebook.ipynb notebook.
Error is:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-34-ec70f70c01d0> in <cell line: 14>()
     14 for i in range(len(attributes)):
     15   # Compute attributes
---> 16   result = sliceAttribute(cube, output='2d', type='il', inline_loc=400,
     17                           attribute_class='CompleTrace',
     18                           attribute_type=attributes[i])


5 frames

/content/computational-geophysics/seismic/attributes/util.py in hilbert(in_data)
    348         ind = [np.newaxis] * in_data.ndim
    349         ind[-1] = slice(None)
--> 350         h = h[ind]
    351     x = np.fft.ifft(Xf * h, axis=-1)
    352     return x


IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

<Figure size 1700x1300 with 0 Axes>
```

and I don't know what is going on. Can U help mi with it?

It maybe some python version problem?